# I just simply typed the code given in tf.Tensor Tensorflow 2.2.0, and here is my code: please i want solution for thi Error

Tags: python-3.x

> I just simply typed the code given in tf.Tensor Tensorflow 2.2.0, and here is my code: please i want solution for thi Error !!

```
print(tf.__version__)
a=2
b=3
c=tf.add(a,b,name='add')
print(c)
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(c))
sess.close()
```

> output

```
2.2.0
tf.Tensor(5, shape=(), dtype=int32)


  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-34-0f2b1dd0c6d9> in <module>()
      4 c=tf.add(a,b,name='add')
      5 print(c)
----> 6 sess = tf.Session()
      7 print(sess.run(c))
      8 sess.close()

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'
```

Comment: try to add import tensorflow as tf at the top of your script and see.

Comment: yes i add it, it's work better, thanks you

Comment: The problem is that `Session` is under the [`compat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/Session) module. `sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()`